# I have 9 small images that when clicked on, will fade in the bigger version of the image. Why wont work in Browser(FF))

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<style type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></style>
<style type="text/javascript" src="myCode.js"></style>
</body> //jquery is within my site directory on my desktop


$(document).ready(function(){
//note:
$("#artShow,#changreImage,#clasziImage,#comicImage,#planetImage,#dragonImage,#wineImage,#underwaterImage,#catImage").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).animate({height:"125px",width:"136px"});
    });
$("#artShow,#changreImage,#clasziImage,#comicImage,#planetImage,#dragonImage,#wineImage,#underwaterImage,#catImage").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).animate({height:"118px",width:"129px"});
    });
```

//note:hover function

//When user clicks on a small image with the prior image hover function, bigger versions 
on that image should fade in//

```
$("#big").hide();
    $("#artShow").click(function(){
        $("#big").fadeIn(2000);
            $("#big").click(function(){
                $("#big").fadeOut(2000);
                });

    });

        $("#big2").hide();
    $("#changreImage").click(function(){
        $("#big2").fadeIn(2000);
            $("#big2").click(function(){
                $("#big2").fadeOut(2000);
                });
    });

            $("#big3").hide();
        $("#clasziImage").click(function(){
            $("#big3").fadeIn(2000);
                $("#big3").click(function(){
                    $("#big3").fadeOut(2000);
                });
        });

            $("#big4").hide();
            $("#comicImage").click(function(){
                $("#big4").fadeIn(2000);
                    $("#big4").click(function(){
                        $("#big4").fadeOut(2000);
                    });
                });

                    $("#big5").hide();
                    $("#planetImage").click(function(){
                        $("#big5").fadeIn(2000);
                            $("#big5").click(function(){
                                $("#big5").fadeOut(2000);
                            });
                        });

                            $("#big6").hide();
                            $("#dragonImage").click(function(){
                                $("#big6").fadeIn(2000);
                                    $("#big6").click(function(){
                                        $("#big6").fadeOut(2000);
                                    });
                                });

                                    $("#big7").hide();
                                    $("#wineImage").click(function(){
                                        $("#big7").fadeIn(2000);
                                            $("#big7").click(function(){
                                                $("#big7").fadeOut(2000);
                                            });
                                        });

                                            $("#big8").hide();
                                            $("#underwaterImage").click(function(){
                                                $("#big8").fadeIn(2000);
                                                    $("#big8").click(function(){
                                                        $("#big8").fadeOut(2000);
                                                    });
                                                });

                                                    $("#big9").hide();
                                                    $("#catImage").click(function(){
                                                        $("#big9").fadeIn(2000);
                                                            $("#big9").click(function(){
                                                                $("#big9").fadeOut(2000);
                                                            });
                                                        });
```

});

Comment: lots of IDs, you should use class.

Comment: Thats not the issue, my external jquery wont link to my HTML file for some reason. I have previously got it to work, but since I re-worked it, its not linking up correctly

Comment: @shawnb Yes until they click on the smaller image again....still not the issue, please dont comment on irrelevant code. Whats wrong with my jquery/javascript link?

Comment: Looks like you have it in your BODY tag. It should be in the HEADER tag.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the irrelevant comment. Where is your jquery file, relative to this HTML file?

Comment: maybe wrarp your code in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @dollarvar because this code could be divide by 8 with classes.

Comment: @MamaWalter Interesting, tell me more!

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></style>
<style type="text/javascript" src="myCode.js"></style>
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myCode.js"></script>
```

?

Comment: Hiding in plain sight.

Answer (score 0):

tag should be `script`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script >
<script type="text/javascript" src="myCode.js"></script>
</body> //jquery is within my site directory on my desktop


$(document).ready(function(){
    //note:
    $(".img")
        .mouseenter(function(){ 
            $(this).animate({height:"125px",width:"136px"});
         })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({height:"118px",width:"129px"});
         });
});
```

myCode.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".big-img").hide();
    $(".img").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data(id);
        $("#"+id)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .click(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(2000);
            });

    });

});
```

HTML image

```
<img class="img" src="" data-id="artShow">
<img class="big-img" src="" id="artShow" >
```

Comment: Ok, now you better post an essay about why `class` is better than `id`?!?